# View poll *results* as anonymous user doesn't allow access

Tags: 7, polls

Has anyone come across this problem before? When an anonymous user tries to view the current poll results (from the current poll block) they get an ACCESS DENIED error. However, if they view the poll (not the results) they can see it just fine.

For example:

http://cypress.supportedns.com/~actionin/node/11/results
(Access denied)

http://cypress.supportedns.com/~actionin/node/11/
(No problem)

In the permissions administrative page, I gave the Anonymous User access to view results, so I'm not sure what's going on. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled upon the same problem when I wanted to redirect some anonymous users to see only the results of a poll depending on what email address pattern they entered in a form before. So I thought sending them to `node/%nid/results` would be fine and somehow it also worked AS LONG AS for testing purpose I didn't vote before (as other anonymous user with allowed email address pattern). Then the IP got stored somehow and when accessing the poll node you automatically get the results view presented WHILE AT THE SAME TIME the `node/%nid/results` URL gets unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what this issue is, but I was able to GET AROUND IT by changing the code in the poll.module file, specifically in the poll_block_latest_poll_view function. I just removed the '/results' string from the URL.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know the problem but when I check this [url](http://cypress.supportedns.com/~actionin/node/11/)
I get the results

so you can use [hook menu alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) to change permission